# function replace_text for entire page

Tags: functions, filters

```
function replace_text($text) {
$text = str_replace('old-text', 'new-text', $text);
return $text;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

Is there any way to apply this to entire page? I mean not only to content but also to header, footer and sidebar too.

Comment: You can use PHP output buffering. Also, [there is a WordPress plugin](https://github.com/dmhendricks/wordpress-output-buffering).

Comment: What's the use case here?

Comment: Thank you. That plugin solved my problem. The reason is to change image urls from site.com/wp-content/uploads to static.site.com. Cdn plugins change to static.site.com/wp-content/uploads so i can not use them.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason is to change image urls from site.com/wp-content/uploads to static.site.com. Cdn plugins change to static.site.com/wp-content/uploads so i can not use them.

I think it's better to update the database content instead of replacing strings in each page-load.

Check this easy DB replacement tool: https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Keep in mind to remove it after you've done your changes!

Comment: Thank you. I knew that but that does not suits my needs. Because when upload new image, WordPress set the link as site.com/wp-content/uploads. So every time I upload new image, I need to update database. It is not useful.